# continously running thread in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

i want a continously running thread in my web application for sending mail to admin if the logged complaint of the user in not solved by technician within 24 hours.

i am able to send mail to administrator

i just want a watch on database for unsolved issues with timespan of more than 24 hours and inform to administrator about the same

how can i perform it. any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Create an aspx page/asmx service to check the database and send email providing appropriate check in the page/service. This page/service can then be called using PowerShell script on the server, and that powershell script can be scheduled to run in task schedular using specified intervals. Hope this shall acheive what you wants.

Comment: I'd agree with Furqan this is probably the way to go.  If you're limited to pure asp.net then there is a technique that was trialled here which might also do the trick.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it would be to write a Windows Service which will monitor the database and send emails out.

Answer (score 0):

If your asp.net web application uses sql server, which i imagine it does, i would reccomend creating a sql agent job which executes some sql with the business logic you desire, and sends emails using the built in sql server email sending functionality

[SQL Server Agent Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188235.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1) Windows service which will monitor the table

2) [SQL Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880.aspx)